# How to get cypress working with a vue.config.mjs file

Tags: javascript, webpack, cypress, vuejs3

I try to write some cypress tests while expanding a larger vue project. This resulted in an error saying that cypress was not translated from typescript to javascript.

I build a minimal test setup, containing the following files:

- `src/components/HelloWorld.vue`

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Vue } from "vue-class-component";

export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {}
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

- `src/components/HelloWorld.cy.ts`

```
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld.vue'

describe('<HelloWorld />', () => {
  it('renders', () => {
    // see: https://test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/
    cy.mount(HelloWorld)
  })
})
```

- `babel.config.cjs`

```
module.exports = {presets: ['@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset']}
```

- `cypress.config.cjs`

```
module.exports = {component: {devServer: {framework: "vue-cli", bundler: "webpack"}}};
```

- `vue.config.mjs`
  Empty
- `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "todoapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^8.0.0-0",
    "vuex": "^4.0.0-0",
    "node-polyfill-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@cypress/vue": "^3.1.0",
    "@cypress/webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.1.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^8.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-0",
    "cypress": "^10.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "typescript": "~4.1.5",
    "vue-jest": "^5.0.0-0"
  }
}
```

- `tsconfig.json`

```
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Here is the detailed error message:

```
The following error originated from your test code, not from Cypress.

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (28:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| // Alternatively, can be defined in cypress/support/component.d.ts
| // with a <reference path="./component" /> at the top of your spec.
> declare global {
|   namespace Cypress {
|     interface Chainable {

When Cypress detects uncaught errors originating from your test code it will automatically fail the current test.

Cypress could not associate this error to any specific test.

We dynamically generated a new test to display this failure.


    at  (webpack://todoapp/./cypress/support/component.ts?:1:8)
    at ./cypress/support/component.ts (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/cypress_support_component_ts.js:17:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:281:43)
    at __webpack_require__.t (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:314:39)
From previous event:
    at runScripts (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:165186:63)
    at onSpecWindow (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:153344:76)
    at init (webpack://todoapp/../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/aut-runner.js?:11:14)
    at  (webpack://todoapp/../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/browser.js?../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/loader.js:19:8)
    at ../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/ (packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/loader.js!../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/browser.js@http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:40:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:281:43)
    at render (webpack://todoapp/../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/browser.js?:3:25)
    at  (webpack://todoapp/../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/@packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/browser.js?:5:2)
    at ../../../../../.cache/Cypress/10.7.0/Cypress/resources/app/node_modules/ (packages/server/node_modules/@cypress/webpack-dev-server/dist/browser.js@http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:30:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:281:43)
    at  (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:535:57)
    at  (http://localhost:8081/__cypress/src/main.js:537:13)
```

I am quite at the end of my rope. Strangely the only change required to get the test running again is to rename `vue.config.mjs` to `vue.config.cjs`, but as the original vue configuration file is a module file, so I cannot accept this as a solution.

Any clues as to where to continue research into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that this behavior resulted from a bug in cypress. Please see [#23896](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/23896) for details.